# Call method passed from redux in react from child to parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

i'm stucked with calling method passed from my main root component to my very nested component. I am passing that function from redux, and somehow I am having problem and i can't execute it...

**postActions.js**

```
export function deletePost(id) {
        const request = axios.delete(`http://localhost:3000/api/posts/${id}`);
        return {
        type: "DELETE_POST",
        payload: request
    }
}
```

**App.js(main root component)**

```
import {deletePost} from "../actions/postActions";
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        post: state.postReducer
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        deletePost:(id)=>{
            dispatch(deletePost(id));
        }
    }
}
```

Also in my App component(root) i have render method with this PropsRoute which is like normal route but allows me to pass props...

```
<PropsRoute path={"/posts/:id/:title"}  deletePost={this.props.deletePost} component={Posts} {...this.props.match} />  

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

**Posts.js**

```
render(){    
    return(
        <div> 
            <main>   
                <Post deletePost={this.props.deletePost)} />
            </main>
        </div>
    ); 
    }
```

**Post.js(here i should to execute it)**

```
render(){
   return (
     <LabelDelete handleDelete={this.deletePost} id={id}  {...this.props.children}/>
   )
}
```

And finally **const LabelDelete**

```
const LabelDelete = (props) => (<span><button onClick={props.handleDelete}>Delete</button></span>);
```

So something here wont work, and i am getting error *TypeError: _this2.deletePost is not a function at handleDelete* and i dont know where to bind *this*...

But it worked since i didn't use this way with redux
it was

```
<LabelDelete handleDelete={this.handleDelete.bind(this)} id={id}  {...this.props.children}/>
```

And **handleDelete** function looked like this:

```
handleDelete(){
    var id = this.props.id; 
    $.ajax({ 
        type:"DELETE",
        url:`http://localhost:3000/api/posts/${id}`, 
        success: function(res) { 
            setTimeout(function () {
              location.pathname="/user";
            }, 500);
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
            console.error(xhr, status, err.toString());
        }.bind(this)
      }); 
  }
```

This worked, but i don't want to use it like this, i want it to be more clear. Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In your Posts.js, you are passing deletePost as props of Post component. Thus, in Post.js, this.deletePost should be changed to this.props.deletePost.

```
render(){
    return (
        <LabelDelete handleDelete={this.props.deletePost} id={id}  
            {...this.props.children}/>
    )
}
```

Comment: yes but deletePost is a function and i have to pass ID, so how should i write it ? like **()=>this.props.deletePost(id)** ? even if i write it i get error _this2.props.deletePost is not a function

Comment: @Ivan well in that case, you can just pass deleteId as another props for LabelDelete and use it in LabelDelete component like this this.props.handleDelelete(this.props.deleteId)